# Prove that $\neg p \to (q \to r)$ and $q \to (p \vee r)$ are logically equivalent using the laws of logical equivalences

Tags: equivalence-relations

Please help, I cannot figure out how   $\neg p \to (q \to r)$  and  $q \to (p \vee r)$ are logically equivalent using the laws of logical equivalences.

Here's what I came up, please help to explain how to show that the equation is logically equivalent using the laws of logical equivalences

$\neg p \to (q \to r)  =  q \to (p \vee r)$

$\neg p (\neg q \vee r)  =  q (p \vee r)$

$p (q \vee r)  =  q \to p$

Thank you!

Comment: use $p \rightarrow q = \neg p \lor q$ .. you seem to change $p \rightarrow q$ into $\neg p  \ q$ ... which I interpret as $\neg p \land q$ ... but it should be $\neg p \color{red}\lor q$! So, for example, $q \rightarrow (p \lor r) = \neg q \lor (p \lor r)$. ... Also, I have no idea what you do on that last line, but that's certainly not correct

Answer (score 0):

~p --> (q --> r)
~~p v (q --> r)
p v (~q v r)
p v (~q) v r
~q v (p v r)
q --> (p v r)

Answer (score 0):

We have $(\neg p\to (q\to r))\equiv (p\lor (q\to r))\equiv (p\lor\neg q\lor r)\equiv (\neg q \lor p\lor r)\equiv (q\to (p\lor r))$.